# Good looking, easy to install alternatives to drywall

Tags: drywall, walls

I'm remodeling my garage and am leaning away from using drywall for wall panels for a few reasons:

- Dust
- Difficult to cut and install
- Too much work ... taping, mudding, sanding, etc
- Would like something more rigid to hang pictures and shelves on

What other options do I have?

I want something that's easy to install, paintable, looks good, and doesn't require a lot of work to hide the seams between panels.

Comment: Drywall may be required by the fire codes.

Comment: How about plywood siding like "T-111"?

Comment: I like the rough-sawn plywood idea. Garage walls get a lot of things mounted to them and a lot of things banged into them. A very smooth surface tends to make dings stand out. A little texture helps hide usage marks.

Comment: If you think drywall is hard to cut watch a few utube videos, if you still think it is tough hire a professional, I can cut sheetrock with a simple box knife for straight cuts in seconds, yes seconds, if cutting an outlet or switch plate a box knife can still be used but a less than 10$ sheetrock saw and a large t square to mark the location takes maybe 2 minute. Since a garrage you will need at least 1 thickness of sheetrock and in some locations 2 with joints offset, check local code to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like MDO plywood (medium density overlay plywood). MDO has a resin paper on one side that you can paint. It comes in 4’ x 8’ x 1/2” thick sheets. (I think it comes thicker too.)

The only way to “cover” the joints is with a batten. However, the edges are trimmed true and straight, so the edges can be butted together easily.

BTW, any wall or ceiling in a garage that is adjacent to a habitable space must have a 1-hour fire rated protection on it...like 5/8” gypsum board Type-X or 1/2” gypsum board Type-C on supports spaces no more than 16” on center. But the MDO can be on top of it for the finish